# Comparison with 0 and JSLint error

Tags: javascript, html, jslint

Here's the code:

```
<input type="number" value="0" id="input">
<script>
  if (document.getElementById('input').value == 0) {
    alert('Hello, world!');
  }
</script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/9hwTb/)**

And here's the JSLint error:

> Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.

But when I listen to the advice and change `==` to `===`, the alert stops appearing.

Comment: Then compare to a string: `=== "0"`, because that's what `.value` returns. Or convert the value to a number first. Always use strict comparison (exceptions: comparing `null` and knowing what you are doing).

Comment: "_Always use strict comparison_" I know it's a good practice, but is there anything wrong with `==` in my demo? Can it cause any problems if I just leave it as is?

Comment: I agree, in this situation type conversion might actually be useful and not harmful. However being consistent is good as well. But imagine what happens if the user provides a non-numerical input (which might be possible depending in the browser). The value would be converted to `NaN` which does not equal 0. Would that be the expected behavior?

Comment: "_imagine what happens if the user provides a non-numerical input_" Nice point! A side note: am I right in my assumption that `input.value == '0'` is faster than `input.value == 0` as the first one doesn't need a conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` returns string. You need to convert it into appropriate format.

1. Use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for  **floating point number**.
2. Use [`parseInt(string,radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for operation on **integers**.

Use

```
if (parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value, 10) === 0) { //Used parse int for integer
```

### OR

```
if (document.getElementById('input').value === "0") { //String comparison
```

Comment: Since it's a number input, we can assume that the value will always be numerical (or at least should be!) and can use `Number(value)` or `+value` to handle both, integers and floats.